# Using org-beamer: display image on every page except the title page

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf, beamer

Using `org-beamer-export-to-pdf` with the following document, I am able to display an image on every slide

```
#+LATEX_HEADER:\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
#+BEAMER_HEADER:\newcommand\AtPagemyUpperLeft[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{\put(\LenToUnit{0.85\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0.9\paperheight}){#1}}}\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\AtPagemyUpperLeft{{\includegraphics[width=1.cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}}}
* A Slide goes here
** With some content
* Another slide
** Yet more content
```

This works well because it places the image on top of the page headers, where other attempts like

```
#+BEAMER_HEADER:\logo{\includegraphics[height=.8cm]{logo.png}\vspace{6cm}\hspace{0.5cm}}
```

The image would be covered by the header.

What I'd like to do now is to skip the title page when displaying the image.

The solutions suggested in TeX forums often suggest placing the `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` after building the title page. However,I'm not sure how to control the placement of that command using org-beamer.

Answer (score 1):

First, a solution for using a logo in the header:

```
#+BEAMER_HEADER:\logo{\includegraphics[height=.8cm]{logo.png}\vspace{6cm}\hspace{0.5cm}}
* A Slide goes here
  :PROPERTIES:
  :BEAMER_OPT: plain
  :END:
** With some content

* Another slide
** Yet more content
```

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-07/msg00116.html

Second, a solution for your actual question:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER:\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
#+BEAMER_HEADER:\newcommand\AtPagemyUpperLeft[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{\put(\LenToUnit{0.85\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0.9\paperheight}){#1}}}

* A Slide goes here
** With some content

* Another slide
#+LATEX: \AddToShipoutPictureFG{\AtPagemyUpperLeft{{\includegraphics[width=1.cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}}}
** Yet more content
```

https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html

Thanks for your question.  It helped me figure out how to put a logo in the header.